# Move data from EBS volume to another volume or mount

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to move large data from EBS volume A to volume B.  Can I just mount volume A to instance B with simple `resize2fs`command? would this format/erase the data in volume A?

In **volume A** I have large directory (300GB) called  `/var/www/html/blog` that I would like to transfer everything to **instance B** to `/app/files/`. Reason for this is that I have purchased pre-built AMI from the marketplace and I want to use the server configuration.

Or is there any good way to transfer data to instance B. Its mostly images and html files.

Answer (score 1):

Take a snapshot of Volume A.  Create a new volume from the snapshot, and associate it with Instance B.  Mount it to Instance B.  Done.

Comment: so resize2fs to instance B will do the job?

Comment: You shouldn't need to issue resize2fs on instance B - the new volume will be a copy of the first volume, and should be the correct size.